# Is there a way to use opacity on the background defined before the last one

Tags: css

I have the following case ( i will nest the CSS within the HTML to save same space):

```
<body style="background: url('someimage.png')">
   <div style="background: white">
      <header style="opacity:0.6">
      </header>
      <article></article>
   </div>
</body>
```

I want the opacity to work for the body's background, not the div's one. And there is no way to make the div's background transparent. I'm looking for effect as the img below. I have the body with a image background, then a div that contains header, article and some many more things I didn't included, but the main div has background white and the i want the header to have this transparent effect from the body's background. And in the same time I'm looking for a responsive solution so photoshop won't help (I think).

[image: the header and article are wrapped in single div]

What you're going to suggest?
Thanks.

---

The main problem that this is a wordpess theme, and I don't want to mess with the HTML structure, I need a CSS solution.

Comment: apply the opacity to what you want it to be?

Comment: I want the opacity to be applied on the header so the background from the body be a bit transparent, but it is working over the  div's background as it is the last background before the header. What do you mean by applying it to the header?

Comment: You could use `background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);`.  This is like just specifying the color, except it makes the `background-color` semitransparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as styling goes, treat the `article` separate of the `header`:

```
<body style="background: url('someimage.png')">
    <div>
        <header style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);border-radius:5px;">
        </header>
        <article style="background: white">
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

*original answer before question edit:*

Applying `opacity:0.6` to `<header>` will only make `<header>` and all of its children transparent. Not the solution.

Applying `opacity:0.6` to `<body>` will make all of its children transparent as well. Not the solution.

**Solution:** Add the transparency to `someimage.png` as an embedded alpha channel within the image, before even using it in the CSS.

Comment: You mean `<body style="opacity:0.6;background:url('someimage.png')">` ?

Comment: That's what I'm referring to in the 2nd paragraph, applying `opacity` to `<body>`, but that is no the solution. Open an image editor (e.g. Adobe Photoshop) and bring the transparency of the layer down to 60% and resave the PNG. Don't even apply `opacity:0.6`.

Comment: Think this won't work for me. I just edited the question so making the case clearer.

Comment: after all the only reasonable thing is really to change the css of all other elements. Thanks